# Javascript change img src on load

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use **Javascript** to change an `img` `src` on load. But what I've got doesn't seem to want to work. Any ideas?

(The difference in the img src is `png` and `svg`)

HTML

```
<img class="fusion-logo-1x" src="//new.network-data-cabling.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/ACCL_Logo.png" width="400">
```

In `<script>` tag in `<head>`

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("fusion-logo-1x").src = "//new.network-data-cabling.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/ACCL_Logo.svg";
};
```

Link to [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0oonLtvy/15/)

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` return nodeList.. Use `id` attribute with `getElementById`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object, You need to use index to iterate and access it's properties.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("fusion-logo-1x")[0].src = "//new.network-data-cabling.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/ACCL_Logo.svg";
```

Comment: Alternatively with [`setAttribute()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) -- `document.getElementsByClassName("fusion-logo-1x")[0].setAttribute("src","//new.network-data-cabling.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/ACCL_Logo.svg");` -- edit SO kills the second slash...

Comment: Ahh, of course! Makes sense that it'd be an array. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use this script

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("fusion-logo-1x")[0].src = "//new.network-data-cabling.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/ACCL_Logo.svg";
};
```